# Flutter UDP Stream Plugin

Tags: flutter, udp, vlc

Is there any flutter Stream player Plugin for UDP Protocol?

I want to stream UDP from my multicast server, already tried a few plugin but nothing work for udp protocol

Comment: You can use raws sockets

Answer (score -1):

You can use
[better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player)
Or
[flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player)